# How can an authentication key be passed to a restful web service?

Tags: web-services, authentication, rest

Some existing web services I consume have methods that look something like this:

```
List<Employee> employees = 
        employeeService.GetEmployees(accessKey, allDepartments);
```

The accessKey serves two purposes; it acts as both authentication and identification.  Only valid access codes are responded to (authentication) and it services as a link to a particular client's data.

If the services were to be done a restful manner I'm not sure how this would be achieved.  I definitely would not want to do something like this:

```
http://www.business.com/<GuidHere>/Employees/
```

Since this would show the accessKey, which is somewhat secret, (ie, its usually in an encrypted file on the client which uses this) we can't show the GUID in a URI.  How is something like this achieved using a restful architecture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could send the authentication token using HTTP headers.

Comment: Yes - the preferred way to do this in a RESTful environment is definitely to put it into a cookie / header.

Comment: Could you paste some code snippets? I am using jersey to consume RESTFul Service

Answer (score 1):

If this is a RESTful *web service* I'm assuming it's being consumed by a machine so why not pass the access key in the url?

At then end of the day you need to put it somewhere and hiding them in hidden form fields in the browser (if the service is to be browsable) isn't much in the way of security.

If the key is so sensitive, why not symmetrically encrypt on the server per session and pass that value around instead?

Just some thoughts.
Kev

Comment: You're probably right... the average user wouldn't see the URL. Perhaps I'm worried about nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If time isn't an issue implementing OAuth security may be useful. OAuth uses a public key, and also a secret. The mess is hashed (in most cases) and the server will use the public key + it's copy of the secret to do the same hashing and make sure its result matches the requests.

The benefit is you wouldn't need to use HTTPS or POST. Get* REST api methods should be using the HTTP GET method (I'm not sure if being RESTful is your goal, just thought I would point that out). I agree with Mr. Pang, use http://www.business.com/employees. The query string could contain the list of department ids.

For your case the service call wouldn't have the 'accessKey' argument, rather it would become the public key (I imagine) and be used in either the headers, query string, or as a POST param.

Some good info on OAuth: http://www.hueniverse.com/hueniverse/

Answer (score 0):

As Troy Alford pointed out, my original suggestion was incorrect. You shouldn't be using POST in a situation like this. You should use a GET request with the authentication information in the HTTP headers. Take a look at [basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) for one way to do that.

Comment: He mentioned this being a RESTful service, though. You shouldn't be using a `POST` verb in a RESTful architecture unless you are saving something to the server.